# Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to execute the above query through java but I get the following error in line 6:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND lexicon_lemma = ?)' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
```

I can't find what is the problem with the syntax... Any suggestion?
This is my query:

```
public static void InsertEntry(String lexiconType, String lemma, String lang) throws SQLException {
    String selectSQL = "SELECT id FROM lexicons WHERE (lexicon_type = ? AND lexicon_lemma = ?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, lexiconType);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, lemma);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
    int id = -1;
    if (rs.next()) {
        id = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println(id);
    } else {
        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO lexicons "
    + "(lexicon_type,lexicon_lemma,lexicon_lang) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
        prepStatement.setString(1, lexiconType);
        prepStatement.setString(2, lemma);
        prepStatement.setString(3, lang);
        prepStatement .executeUpdate();
        prepStatement.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error stack posted is incomplete. Post it with sql statement included as seen in error stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no necessity to pass sql statement variable to `executeQuery` for `PreparedStatement`. That is the main issue in your case.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, lexiconType);
preparedStatement.setString(2, lemma);
// error is in the following statement
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

As you are *resetting* the sql to be executed, the statement is not recognized as prepared statement but an instance of parent `Statement` which is looking for valid inputs in between quotes for stings etc. which are not present. And hence is the Syntax error.

**Change**:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

**To**:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

And it should be working.

**Refer**:

> [PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery())

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);`

to

`ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();`

Comment: Why? and what is the difference? And putting `'?'` in single quotes and using `prepared statement` is not going to work.

Comment: In SQL queries, strings are enclosed within a pair of single quotes.

Comment: With `java` and `prepared statement` enclosing in single quotes is not correct.

Comment: I have tried it without parenthesis but without enclosing `?` in single quotes, but same error as well.

Comment: sorry my mistake...the error is here in `ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);` change it as `ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();` and no need to add single quotes